# catkin_make -j2

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Me and a fellow student is working on an Autonomous boat project, and while building catkin folders, we struggled with normal use of catkin_make. Tutorials referred to the option -j2 as argument. What does this actually do? we are using a raspberry pi 3b with ubuntu mate.

Thanks

- Andreas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257737/catkin_make--j2/) by [andreasvo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29800/andreasvo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2017-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the `-j` option, you specify the number of threads to use when compiling. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html).

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.ros.org/users/20033/nlamprian/) with karma: 366 on 2017-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andreasvo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29800/andreasvo/) on 2017-03-23**:
Thanks, that makes a lot of sense now!